# Can't access app in sharepoint 2013

Tags: app

I'm working with SP on server by using my laptop to remote to server. I've create app on this site : http://mycompany.net/develop and deploy it successfully on server, and the URL of app is: apps-22k1ishhud98s.abc.net (apps: is prefix and abc.net: is domain for app that I was set before). The problem is, I can not access to the app when using my laptop. So can u guys help me out of this.
This is my site look like. [image: This page can't be display]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the result I see in Fiddler is error 502

Comment: In short, try opening port 100 on server, or check other firewall-related settings. The issue is related to firewall either on server or on laptop or somewhere in between.

Comment: In my case, I can access to both my app webplication, site collection at http://mycompany.net and http://mycompany.net/dev , but I can not access my Application for Sharepoint 2013 at apps.appID.mycompany.net. When I try to access I got error "This page can’t be displayed"